# Can't catch a http error in component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a problem with Angular 5, HTTP interceptor and errorHandler.

I send a http request. The response can be a 200 or a 404 (if the data doesn't exist). 200 works perfectly with the subscribe into the component. The 404 is different because I'm using HttpInterceptor from angular. If there is an error, the "catch error" function sends back an Observable error but I can't catch this error from my service or my component and I don't know why.

**test.component.ts**

```
this.testService.findByProducId(product.id).subscribe(data => {

                console.log(data); 

                // processing
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err); // nothing here :(

            });
```

**test.service.ts**

```
    findByProductId(productId){
        let url = this.getUrl() + "/product/" + productId;

        // headers
        let headers = this.setHttpHeaders();

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res).share();
    }
```

**httpListener (interceptor)**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpListener implements HttpInterceptor {

    countRequest: number = 0;
    countResponse: number = 0;
    logEnable: boolean = environment.logEnable;
    logUrl: string = environment.logUrl;

    constructor(
        @Inject( LoaderService ) public loaderService: LoaderService,
        @Inject( Router ) public router: Router) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.loaderService.show();
        this.countRequest++;

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    if (this.logEnable) {
                        // log data
                    }
                } 

                return event;
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                if (this.logEnable) {
                    // log data
                }

                switch(error.status) {
                    case 400: {
                        break;
                    }

                    // not authorized
                    case 401: {
                        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 404: {
                        // my specific 404 case
                        if (!this.router.url.includes("/test/create")) {

                        }
                        else {

                            // I want to return the error to my service.
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Observable.throw(error);
            }),
            finalize(() => {

                this.countResponse++;

                if (this.countRequest == this.countResponse) {
                    this.loaderService.hide();

                    this.countRequest = 0;
                    this.countResponse = 0;
                }
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is the program entering `catchError`  once a 404 is thrown ?

Comment: Yes that's it. I can see an error in the catchError function but I can't send back it (I tried with an Observable but nothing appears in my service or my component)

Comment: Why are you catching that error in a HttpInterceptor? You should use catchError when you call your service, and do the check for a 404 there.

Comment: The interceptor to "intercept" all http request and when there is an error a notification is displayed for the client (and a log is sent by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

component.ts

```
this.testService.findByProducId(product.id).subscribe(

    data => console.log('success', data),
    error => console.log('oops', error));
```

service.ts

```
return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers}) 
            .map((response: Response) =>response.json())
```

Comment: I tried your code but I've nothing inside the subscribe. Even into the service, I had a console.log but nothing. I don't understand :(

Oh I've some error when I compile. I'll edit my comment asap

Comment: I can compile but still the problem. Nothing back to my component. Same thing inside my service (I tried to console.log the response)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. The function "catchError" inside my interceptor seems to stop the process. Here the good code (maybe I could use "catch" function but I've got an error) :

```html
            error => {
                if (this.logEnable) {
                    // log data
                }

                switch(error.status) {
                    case 400: {
                        break;
                    }

                    // not authorized
                    case 401: {
                        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 404: {
                        // my specific 404 case
                        if (!this.router.url.includes("/test/create")) {

                        }
                        else {

                            // I want to return the error to my service.
                            Observable.of(error);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Observable.throw(error);
            }),
```